# Extendable global config for an Angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, app-config, angularjs-module

I'm looking to include global options for an Angular directive/module.

I could use a `.constant()` (or simply an object of configs) in my module file, but since the module is designed for other people to include in their projects, and is installable via Bower, I don't like the idea of global options being blown away when the module gets an update. I'm aware that the `.constant()` could be included in another file, but then the user *has to* include it - rather I'd prefer that the module included everything (default values), and then the user could extend/modify if required.

I'm envisioning a similar approach as to a jQuery plugin pattern such as:

```
$('.myElement').myPlugin({
    option1: '',
    option2: ''
});
```

**The Plugin**

```
(function($) {
    $.myPlugin = function( element, conf ) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var defaults = {
            option1: '',
            option2: '',
        };
        var config = $.extend( defaults, conf );

        //...

    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(config) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('myPlugin')) {
                var plugin = new $.myPlugin(this, config);
                $(this).data('myPlugin', plugin);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your App and Configuring the Module**

This is where we can define a configuration block and inject a provider. From this we can set our config options.

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp', ['myModule'] )

myApp.config( function( myDirectiveConfigProvider ) {
    myDirectiveConfigProvider.config = {
        option1: 'A new setting'
        //option2: 'A new setting'
    };

    // OR

    myDirectiveConfigProvider.config.option1 = 'A new setting';
    //myDirectiveConfigProvider.config.option2 = 'A new setting';
});
```

**The Module**

Within the module we can define a service to hold our default config options. This could also simply be included in the directive if you don't wish to inject it `var config = {}`.

We also define a Provider which will be injected into our configuration block.

Within the directive we simply need to extend `config` (injected service or var) with the providers.

```
angular.module( 'myModule', [] )

    .value( 'config', {
        'option1': 'my default setting',
        'option2': 'my default setting'
    })


    .directive( 'myDirective', [ 'config', 'myDirectiveConfig', function( config, myDirectiveConfig ) {
        return {
            link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

                angular.extend( config, myDirectiveConfig.config );

                console.log( config.option1 ); //'A new setting'
                console.log( config.option2 ); //'my default setting'
            }
        }
    }])

    .provider( 'myDirectiveConfig', function() {
        var self = this;
        this.config = {};
        this.$get = function() {
            var extend = {};
            extend.config = self.config;
            return extend;
        };
        return this;
    });
```